# Error with calling FileProvider from DialogFragment - null object of reference,

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-fileprovider

I am trying to fix this error but I am kind of not seeing where it comes from.

From my fragment which creates new user I am calling another fragmentDialog (on ImageButton Click) which enables me to pick a photo from camera or gallery. Gallery works fine, but camera does not. In this line:

```
 Uri photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(globalContext, getActivity().getPackageName() + ".provider", getCameraFile());
```

I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

All the data is displaying correctly (I check in logs).

Where cna be the issue?

Regards,
Grzegorz

EDIT:

Full stack trace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.myapp.myapp, PID: 27523
                                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:583)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:557)
                                                                                 at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:399)
                                                                                 at com.myapp.myapp.utils.PictureDialog.onTakePhoto(PictureDialog.java:80)
                                                                                 at com.myapp.myapp.utils.PictureDialog_ViewBinding$1.doClick(PictureDialog_ViewBinding.java:32)
                                                                                 at butterknife.internal.DebouncingOnClickListener.onClick(DebouncingOnClickListener.java:22)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5184)
                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20893)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5940)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
```

Comment: `globalContext` is `null`, most likely. Please edit your question and post the entire Java stack trace, not just the one line.

Comment: It is not, it is my variable which takes the context from onAttach. I have also used getActivity() and getApplicationContext() instead of it with the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileProvider` cannot find the `<provider>` element in the manifest that has an `android:authorities` value equal to `getActivity().getPackageName() + ".provider"`. Specifically, this code results in a `null` value for `info`:

```
final ProviderInfo info = context.getPackageManager()
            .resolveContentProvider(authority, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

(where `context` is the first parameter to `getUriForFile()` and `authority` is the second parameter to `getUriForFile()`)

Make sure that your supplied authority string matches your `<provider>` element.